# How can I create a sequence of triggers on GTM across multiple pages for one tag

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to set up a tag and triggers on GTM to have an event track across multiple pages. ie click on a button which takes the user to a contact page and once the form is submitted a tag is fired. I can set up this if the triggers are all on one page but it seems GTM refreshes the triggers on a per page basis and so a sequence of actions across multiple pages is not as simple.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking a sequence with Google Tag Manager is a super interesting use case. I've never needed this before but now I can think of quite a few applications.

The problem is that triggers in GTM are primarily based on the dataLayer object in the browser, which is not persistent.  What that means is that when the user moves from one page to another, the data vanishes.

So here is another awesome solution using ListenLayer.com, which gives you the ability to spin up some cool browser tracking around the data layer and then monitor it.

Basically, a Listener will automatically push data into the data layer when your button is clicked. You can write a rule in ListenLayer to store a value from the data layer in the user's Session Storage to save the fact that they clicked on the button.  ListenLayer will then automatically push data into the data layer when the form is submitted, and you can write rules to get values out of Session Storage and put it back into the data layer when the form is submitted.

So when the form is submitted, you will have a data layer event  that will have a variable indicating whether the user first clicked on your button prior to submitting the form. In GTM you can simply reference this data layer event and look for the variable value inside a trigger - and whala! You have a trigger in GTM that will only fire if the user clicked the button and then submitted the form.

That was a high level explanation, so here are the details.

**Step 1:** Create a ListenLayer account and turn on the Internal Clicks Listener and its features. Publish your changes and make sure the script is on your website. etc.

**Step 2:** Take a look at your data layer activity and click the button. You can preview this in GTM or just look in the console. It will look like this [image: will look like] when you click any internal link on your website (I'm assuming your button is an internal link, you can otherwise use the Outbound Clicks listener)

Notice that the data layer activity has a bunch of variables like the click text, location, etc. These are just like variables in the GTM data layer.  In ListenLayer you will see them start to appear under Variable Settings and you can use them to write rules.

**Step 3:**  Make sure the Browser Storage feature is turned on inside the Internal Clicks Listener.  Then create a Global Browser Variable [image: create a Global Browser Variable] (I am using a session key because I assume you want the sequence to occur in 1 session, otherwise use Local Storage). I am calling mine clickedButton.

**Step 4:** Create a browser storage rule inside the Internal Clicks Listener.  Basically under the Internal Clicks Listener is a menu item called Browser Storage (As long as the feature is enabled). Create a new Session Storage rule under that.  We want to save a value in our new Session Storage key from the previous step, but only if the user clicks the correct button.

You're going to have to write your own rule to identify your button click specifically, but here is an example [image: here is an example]. You can see my condition requires a specific data layer event (internalLinkClick) and then I'm going to look at the URL where the click was located and the URL where the user click to.  These are elements inside my data layer event from above, so I am using them to identify this specific button.  But you may want to use things like click text, xpath etc. which are all available in the data layer automatically.

Next, inside the same rule you will choose a value to save in the session key.  I am just going to save a yes[image: going to save a Yes]. So now whenever someone clicks this button, they will get the value "yes" stored in a session storage key called clickedButton. That value will exist until they close the tab.

**Step 5:** Publish your changes and test it out.  I went to my website and clicked the button and looked at the applications tab of inspector and I see a yes in my session storage. You can see it here [image: You can see it here].

**Step 6:** Okay so now we need to know when a user submits the form. Depending on your form system ListenLayer might have a listener that is [custom built to automatically track form submissions](https://www.listenlayer.com/listeners/forms/) and push all the details into the data layer.  If not, just use the Custom Forms listener. Turn it on and turn on all the Form Activity features.

If you use this particular listener you need to tell ListenLayer what forms to listen for so they should have a class or ID or name element in the `<form>` tag and you can write a rule under event settings to identify the form. [image: Here you can see] I want the tool to listen for my forms that have one of two classes. Anyway, you'll need to work on getting your forms identified, it's pretty easy. Then you'll want to publish the changes and test out the form.  You should see data layer activity like this[image: like this] when a form is submitted.

**Step 7:** Okay we are almost there. This is the finale!  We will create a custom data layer variable to push the value of the session storage key into when a the form is submitted.  So first, under the Custom Forms Listener, you'll want to turn on the Custom Data Layer Values feature. Then under Global Custom Data Layer Variables create a new variable. I am creating [image: I am creating] one call didUserClickButton.  Then click on custom values inside the menu under the Custom Forms Listener and create a Simple Rule. What we will do is write a condition to identify when this form submits and we will pull the value from the Session Storage and push it into the data layer. Again, write the rule that you need to identify your form, mine looks like this[image: mine looks like this] and I could add a URL in the value field.

On the next step, choose to insert the value from the session storage key like shown here[image: like shown here]. Save and publish.

Now test your form submission. If you have a value in the session storage, the form submission event in the data layer will contain this custom value [image: contain this custom value], and if not it will look like this [image: it will look like this].

Boom!  Now you have a perfect data layer event named `customFormSubmitted` and a variable `formCustomValues.didUserClickButton` that you can simply reference in GTM to build a trigger. I assume you know how to do that. If not, look up how to create a custom event trigger based on a data layer, and how to register and use a custom data layer variable.

Here is the coolest part: If you program this from scratch, you have to manage the code and make sure it doesn't break, and document it. With ListenLayer it's all visual and once it's built you can write monitoring rules in the platform to notify you if something breaks with your setup.